# css3 media query not working only in specific div

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a bunch of media queries on my page but for some reason the one I have that targets a div in my footer won't work. Is there something I'm doing wrong with the notation?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
.twitterbutton {
    background-size: 50%;
    }
}
```

normally the background-size is 100%, but it's squishing itself on a few displays. Any suggestions as to why it's not working? Thank you!

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing more code. Did you type the class name incorrectly, or have another rule set that is more specific and it overriding it?

Comment: I guess, Background-size is having 2 values instead of 1. I Hope you browser is supporting the background-size CSS3 style!

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the responses! @DavidStorey, the class is typed correctly and even when I disabled all my other media queries it was not working. I'm not sure if there are any rules that would override it... I thought media query was given the priority when determining the class's data? Is there something that could override it??

Comment: @iCybernetics hmmm maybe, I don't know why the media query wouldn't be overriding the old value though :( my browser does support background-size! Fully updated chrome :)!

Comment: A media query has zero specificity. Any declaration where the selector has higher specificity than the selector inside the @media at-rule will override it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DavidStorey, the issue was that I needed to put the media query *after* the original lines of css due to the specificity being higher in the original lines of code this way! Thanks!